# how to add today date as default value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

in sql server. my `database` name RequestInfo, I have a table name RequestedDate, which have data type is `datetime`. now i want when ever the value of  other columns of table is inserted, then automatically in the RequestedDate `column`, today date should inserted. 
i am using this `query` but it shows no today in built function.

```
alter table RequestInfo add default Today() for RequestedDate
```

Comment: Try `now()`, but you might need to set up a trigger; if you just use alter table, you might set a default date of whenever it was you set up the default.

Comment: now it got the answer
alter table RequestInfo add default getdate() for RequestedDate

Answer (score 4):

**Define Default Value When Creating Table**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
DATECOLUMN DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE() --<-- Default Value
)
```

**Already Existing Table on already Existing Column**

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR DATECOLUMN
```

**Add a new Column to an Existing Table With Default Value**

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD New_DATE_COLUMN DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE ADD Date_Created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```